# How to square a velocity vector?

Tags: vectors, fluid-dynamics

I've just looked at Bernoulli's equation $\frac 12 \mathbf V^2- \Phi+\frac{p}{\rho}=\rm constant$. Since $\mathbf V$ is a velocity vector how is it squared? Is each component squared separately?

Comment: This is rather poor form when it comes to notation. They are implying the squared norm - it would be better written as $\Vert\mathbf{V}\Vert^2$ or just $V^2$. However, the presence of the $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ confuses me.

Comment: ahh thank you very much, and sorry  Φ wasn't supposed to be a vector I don't think

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf V^2$ simply means $\mathbf V \cdot \mathbf V $, where $\cdot $ is the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). It implies the squared  norm $\|\mathbf V\|^2$.